# Get student email from userID

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-classroom

I have been able to get the courses and studentsubmission lists from classroom successfully.

I now want to get email address for students rather than use the userID that studentsubmission returns.
https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users very usefully says use userProfiles.get  so using this line =

```
studentEmail = service.userProfiles().get(userId = student['userId'])
```

which results in the following output:

```
<googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x0000000003F9C048> TURNED_IN
```

As expected I have 1 student in the test classroom and 1 student who has finished the work.  But that is clearly not an email address!
So what do I need to do please with my get()?  I have tried

```
get().getEmailaddress()
```

But that doesn't seem to work and docs are a little vague for me.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT ***

made a couple of changes so my loop now looks like this
    students = studentSubmissionResults.get('studentSubmissions', [])

```
for student in students:
    studentId = service.userProfiles().get(userId = 
                student['userId']).execute()
    studentEmail = studentId.get('emailAddress').execute()
    assignmentState = student['state']
    print('The following students have completed the work:\n', studentEmail 
           , assignmentState )
```

this has resulted in a insufficient scope error, but I have all the scopes suggested on the userProfile.get() page ? ? ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, it appears you should use

```
.get('emailAddress')
```

on the result of the `userProfiles.get(userId)` call.

In addition, you should wrap this call in a `try-except` block to handle failures in your request.

Comment: thats what I thought but any combination I try seems to end with an 'object has no attribute' error.

Comment: So I made a couple of changes

Comment: OK Marking Pedro as correct as it was a get() ON THE RESULT and a few scope changes.  Then I had to re authorise the to allow the for the change in scopes.